# Sometimes I move like a snake other times I hit like a stone , What am I?

Tags: riddle, science

> Sometimes I move like a snake other times I hit like a stone.
>
> I move very quickly , very faster than you.
>
> Try to race me and win , I will show you a magic trick that no magician has ever performed.

What am I?

Comment: any more clue...

Comment: the magic trick is showed if i win?

Comment: @lois6b magic will be shown every time you win..

Comment: when you say "I move very quickly , faster than you." is always or you can do it sometimes?

Comment: @lois6b most of the time ,it requires extreme efforts to win..

Comment: @AmruthA, regarding my (accepted) answer, your last comment is quite missleading...

Comment: @Christoph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light

Comment: I downvote cause the clues/hints/comments are not valid. I know is you riddle, but you cant misslead. Nothing is faster than light. "extreme effort to win" lool

Comment: @lois6b ok , I don't mind downvote but feel the puzzle is correct , and I have not told anything wrong , see the link above to find out how to travel faster than light.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit of a strech, but could it be

> Light?

Sometimes I move like a snake other times I hit like a stone.

> Photons may be described as wave, or particles.

I move very quickly , faster than you.

> With the speed of light, obviously.

Try to race me and win, I will show you a magic trick that no magician has ever performed.

> So here comes the strechy part: it's physically impossible to win against the light. But I'm sure that if someone finally moves faster than light, magic things will happen!

Comment: Are you kidding me? I thought about putting light but that last clue...

Comment: @Areeb https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light

Comment: ehmmmm OP? i asked: "when you say 'I move very quickly , faster than you.' is always or you can do it sometimes?" you answered: "most of the time ,it requires extreme efforts to win.."

Comment: @AmruthA the reason I didn't put that is because of what lois described.

Comment: @lois6b what is wrong with most of the time ,it requires extreme efforts to win.. it very difficult to travel faster than light ..

Comment: Weeell. I thought about it but last clue definitlly discard this option for me. So i posted about sound as an answer. Good game anyway.

Comment: because lightspeed is not the max speed possible per se. the limit is because the causality principle. if in a road the limit is 120mph and my car maximum speed is 120mph, my car is not the limit, it just happen to go at this speed. if the causality principle stated a higher speed, light would be faster. so "most of the time" is not correct. and you can never go faster than light

Comment: @AmruthA Current scientific models predict it is not "very difficult to travel faster than light", but impossible. To travel faster than light would break most ways we know how the universe works.

Comment: @JamesTrotter You can most definitely go faster than light as long as you don't race light in vacuum. If you've ever seen a nuclear pool with that distinctive blue tint, you've witnessed particles going faster than light *in water*.

Comment: @AmiralPatate I suppose its how you choose to compare it, i can travel faster in a vacuum than light can in water, but I cannot travel faster than light in water.

Answer (score 4):

Its :

> A photon

Sometimes I move like a snake other times I hit like a stone.

> A photon can be considered a wave or a particule

I move very quickly , faster than you.

> Light is fast!

Try to race me and win , I will show you a magic trick that no magician has ever performed.

> Travelling faster than light is going back in time

Comment: ok more precise but late ..

Answer (score 2):

> My shadow?

Sometimes I move like a snake other times I hit like a stone.

> Depending on what you cast a shadow on it could look waving, like a snake or it could suddenly get shorter, i.e. drop like a stone.

I move very quickly , faster than you.

> If the light source is behind you the shadow will be in front of you.

Try to race me and win , I will show you a magic trick that no magician has ever performed.

> For the keen runners, try and race with your shadow.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's

> sound

It moves like a snake when it's

> music

Which can be

> hard **rock**

It travels at around

> 1000km/h

which is pretty fast.

It creates a

> shock wave

when you go faster than it, which is amazing.

Not sure of the answer, but it fits most of the phrases.

Comment: so close but not answer , may be some else will get inspired by your answer

Answer (score 1):

> Lightning.

1st stanza

> When lightning strikes it has a snake-like appearance,

2nd Stanza

> when it hits it will leave quite an impact (stone).

3rd stanza

> It is very fast at 220,000,000 miles per hour.

Last part

> The "magic show" is it's brilliant spectacle.